# Fixed Page Scrolling

Tags: html, css, mobile, polymer

On **iOS**, as you scroll on [Google's I/O Event page](https://events.google.com/io2015/), the height of Safari's address bar does not get reduced. However, if you scroll on ANY other website, Safari's address bar shrinks.

How is this achievable? I've been trying to look through their CSS code. I think they're using Polymer for their site.

Scrolled to the bottom of the page in both screenshots, see the height difference in Safari's address bar.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this happen _only_ on iOS? Is there any way it can be reproduced otherwise?

Comment: Oh, ok, I see what you mean. It also happens on Android Firefox. It doesn't look like something that would happen on desktop browsers.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yes seems to be mobile only. Let me add screenshots.

Comment: I edited so that the images are more easily comparable. Rollback if you think it makes it less clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an iphone at hand to test it but I think this is because they have

```
<core-draw-panel>  set to overflow: hidden;
```

and child element

```
<div main> set to overflow-y: scroll;
```

I think this prevents url bar hiding on scroll.

Comment: Huh. I was thinking it was going to be much more complex than this, but that makes sense.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Hmm, same. Thanks for this answer. I will test it out. Lajon, can you explain why/how this works?

Comment: Minimizing top and bottom bars in iOS works with the native scrolling. If you switch it off and add scrolling to any other element on the page the safari bars will not shrink. Here it looks a little bit tricky as I can't see overflow: hidden; on body or html element but it looks like [core-draw-panel](https://developers.google.com/web/shows/polycasts/season-1/core-drawer-panel?hl=en) is responsible for scrolling on the page thats why overflow: hidden; is specified on this element.

Comment: Long story short add overflow: hidden to body, html element on any page and add scrolling to the child element and safari bars will not shrink.

Comment: @Lajon Thanks for the explanation!